# How send downloaded file as response in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to download file from remote SFTP server and send that file as response in browser.

I use next code to this task but has little problem.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const remotePath = '/reports/' + 'daly.csv'

  const localePath = path.join(process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE, 'downloads/daly.csv')

  sftp.connect(config.sftpServer, 'on').then(() => {
    const options = {
      root: path.join(process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE, 'downloads'),
      dotfiles: 'deny',
      headers: {
        'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
        'x-sent': true
      }
    }

    sftp.fastGet(remotePath, localePath, {}).then(() => {
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=daily.csv')
      res.sendFile('daily.csv', options)
    })

  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
})
```

As you can see I use `fastGet` method of [ssh2-sftp-client](https://github.com/jyu213/ssh2-sftp-client) library for download the file from remote server to local machine of the user. After that I use `sendFile` method of Express Framework. In the final I have 2 same csv files in local folder of user computer. How to fix this problem?

Comment: what is the problem ? What response are you getting in the browser ?

Comment: `fastGet`method download file from remote SFTP server to local path of user computer. In local folder I see `daily.csv` file in that step. I need to send that file as response in browser. If I use `sendFile` method it create the same file with the same name in local path. For example in browser I see `daily(1).csv` file as response. That behavior is not correct. Its the problem. Do you understand me?

Comment: Right now I can use next code at the end `fs.unlink(localePath)`. This code delete one of the file. So finally I have one file in folder but it seems to me not best practice. Also in console I notice error like this: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent`. Do you have any ideas, bro?